# Изменение значения в поле по кнопке mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть PHP, где выводится список пользователей с их данными из БД, которые вносятся при регистрации. На каждую запись повесил поле, где можно изменить номер телефона и кнопку, чтобы сохранять в БД (доступно только администратору). Как сделать так, чтобы номер изменялся/добавлялся только в том поле, где были изменены/добавлены данные и нажата кнопка. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Поле и кнопка - составная часть отображения записи. У записи есть некое идентифицирующее значение (например, ID). Это значение должно присутствовать в данных на странице (возможно, в скрытой форме) и передаваться вместе с новым значением поля при нажатии кнопки на сервер, где использоваться в качестве условия отбора в запросе на обновление.

Comment: ID есть у каждой записи. Какой запрос нужно отправлять, чтобы редактировать именно ту запись, которую, соответственно, редактирую? PHP изучаю совсем недавно.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET phone=new_phone_from_form WHERE id = id_from_form`

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, про id_from_form.
Это имя формы, я так понял?

Comment: Как это все накинуть на кнопку и отследить ID записи?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Написал на js+ajax

Answer (score 0):

У вас неверное представление данных. Нужно выводить список пользователей и сделать возможность редактирования по отдельности: возле каждого пользователя вывести кнопку или сделать кликабельным самого юзера. А далее вместе с изменёнными данными отсылать ID и по нему апдейтить запись в БД.

Comment: Все так и есть, кнопки есть на всех записях. Просто не понимаю, какой запрос нужно отсылать, чтобы изменялся только тот ID, на котором была нажата кнопка. Как сделать - понимаю, как реализовать - нет.

Comment: Что означает какой запрос? Вы отсылаете данные на бекенд а он уже формирует sql запрос на изменение данных в БД.

Comment: Как в запросе указать, что данные нужно взять из поля, в которое вводится номер телефона?

Comment: Ну так здесь множество вариантов. Если без использования каких-либо фрейморков или плагинов, то, как вариант, нативным образом - поля каждого пользователя включить в отдельную форму HTML, action которой, будет отсылать все содержащие input элементы.

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался. Можно какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: <form action="/updateUser" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form> Не забудьте еще добавить скрытое поле для передачи ID пользователя на бекенд.